# Why the div is not centred

Tags: css, css-transforms

im triying to center this element in the screen, and also when i hover.

In my example below, the div is not centred, even when i hover it knowing that i made the transform 50% and top/left too, that's what i use uselly to center an element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
position: relative }

.zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform .2s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  transform: scale(.2) translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.5); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="zoom"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that the `transform` property has not needed those vendor prefixes in at least 10 years. Are you really supporting IE9 and Safari 8?

Comment: yes i know, it was just generated by the editor i deleted them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind the order of the transforms determines how the element appears. You first move the element `top: 50%; left: 50%;`, which puts it in the bottom right quadrant. Then you make it smaller `transform: scale(0.2)` and **then** you move it left by 50% of its now smaller size `translate(-50%, -50%)`.

By placing the translate first, the element is centered **before** becoming smaller. Remember to also include the `translate(-50%, -50%)` when you increase the size, as the consequent translates will **overwrite** the current one, not add to it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
position: relative }

.zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform .2s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(.2);
  position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="zoom"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

the bug is in `:hover` selector because without `translate()` inside the transform, you basically reset it to 0 which isn't what you want.
because it will forget what was before and override it.

**here is a simple solution here:**

❌

```css
.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5); 
}
```

✅

```css
.zoom:hover {
  transform: 
     scale(1.5)
     translate(-50%, -50%); /* add this */
}
```

**here is a simple explanation here:**

[image]

---

**Modern solution (less code):**

using CSS grid https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid

with `place-items` it will center it automatically without the need for any transform or position... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items

also, you don't have to `0.2` the scaling at the start, just start at `scale(1)` and then make it bigger with a bigger scale in hover like `4` for example. (so it won't create that bug at the start of from 200px to 0.2scale transition without any hover)

---

however, if you want to make the CSS work also in IE and older browsers then is good to use position, and translate, top, left...

but your users are using a modern browser, so for readability and making a simpler use of flexbox or grid can be a great idea.

for any further info use https://caniuse.com (for example grid is 95% supported by any browser from 2020 one, and in chrome from 2017)

---

---

**here the CSS grid solution**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.zoom {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(4);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="zoom"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `translate(-50%, -50%)` *before*  `scale(0.2)`. Also, you need to include the `translate(-50%, -50%)` in your `hover` rule, otherwise it scales, but resets the translate part to its default.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative
}

.zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform .2s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: center;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5);
  /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="zoom"></div>

</body>

</html>
```